# GWT unique hardware identifier

Tags: gwt, hardware

I am using GWT on the client side to connect to an application server and would like to know if there is any unique hardware identifier accessible (through GWT or a servlet), such that I could allow certain machines to access my content, and reject other machines.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You won't be able to get any hardware info (like MAC address) from your client with GWT.

Using `getThreadLocalRequest().getRemoteAddr();` you'll be able to get the IP address if you know them and they don't change it may be a solution

Comment: I can't use IP addresses because I don't use static IP's

Comment: @newuser Then I'm afraid you'll have to : 1/ do the classic login/pass 2/ Use some SingleSignOn manager

Comment: Ended up going with a third party VPN tunneling service, IP address would be suitable in most cases